# How to include navigation arrows and progress bar on stacked cards

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a swappable Stacked Cards available at CodePen: https://codepen.io/bmarcelino/pen/vRYPXV

I'm trying to input 2 arrows to navigate (left and right) and create a progress bar (to each card swapped) like this :

[image]

I'm using bootstrap and I was able to create the progress bar, but I could not communicate with the stake cards or make the arrows work. I tried this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

How Can I do this?